# jquery help --inserting values into form using DB

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am building a php page something like this ..

A jquery syntax decleration

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get(){
$.post('output.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output) {
$('#age').html(output).show();
}) ;
}
</script>
```

The form structure .
The information of the id entered here will be fetched from a database using output.php file

```
<body> 
<p>
<form name="form">
id:
<input type ="text" name="name"><input type ="button" name="Submit_1" 
value="Get          
Existing Data" onclick="get();">
</body>
```

Output.php echos the following values from the database which will be displayed on the same page using jquery & ajax

```
$age= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM parentid WHERE id ='$name'");
$age_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($age);   
if ($age_num_rows==0)
echo "id does not exist";

else
{
$sql ="SELECT * FROM parentid WHERE id = '$name'";       
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$abc_output= "Existing data of the record <br />";      
$abc_output .="Title: " . $row['title'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="Report No: " .  $row['reportno'] . "<br />" ;
$abc_output .="URL: " .  $row['calc_url'] . "<br />" ; 
$abc_output .="Institution: " .  $row['institution'] . "<br />" ; 
}
}
echo $abc_output;
```

The output of the above program will be something like

Form structure for id:

After entering id info of title,report no. ..will be displayed on the same page

..

Now what i want to do is

I will be creating the form structure for title , etc.,
something like this..

```
<p>title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>     

<p>reportno:<input type="text" name="reportno"/></p>

 <p>url: <input type="text" name="calc_url"/></p>
```

The information that is obtained from the database should be inserted into these forms ..these forms will be on the initial page..

How can i do this??

Thanks for u r time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create an associative array to hold the values you're returning rather than appending the strings. You can encode that object as JSON using json_encode. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
  $output = array("name" => "john");
  echo json_encode($output);
```

then you can access the array by the key in javascript. Something like..

```
$('#name-textbox').val(output.name);
```

where "output" is the json object you returned.